# OWL API V5 read ontology from local file

Tags: owl-api

in the current documentation example at the link:
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java
There is no example of how to load an ontology from a local file. There is only a way to load it from a string.

In the past when i used owl-api version 3
the following code worked perfectly:

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager =OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File file = new File (path);
    OWLOntology ont = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create(file));
```

however, in this version, the last line of the previous code:

```
manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create(file));
```

returns this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SAXParsers.initParserWithOWLAPIStandards(Lorg/xml/sax/ext/DeclHandler;)Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParser; 
        at 
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:148)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:62)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.load(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:954)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:918)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:859)
    at glass.main.ontology_Test_main2.readOntology(ontology_Test_main2.java:49)
    at glass.main.ontology_Test_main2.main(ontology_Test_main2.java:38)
```

Kindly note the attachment, a small test java project, link:

dropbox.com/s/3787a3gsk2bwc26/test.tar.gz?dl=0

Kindly what am i doing wrong, i m sure that this code

Kindly would you please provide the correct way to do it, and add it to the tutorial example in the link https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java

Thanks very much for your time.
Sincere regards

Comment: The root of your problem is conflicting versions of the library. Check your classpath - very likely there will be more than one OWLAPI version mentioned in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem was:

The previous versions that i was using:
I was using Hermit version 1.3.8.500 and OWL-API previous version 5.0.5 got modified it seems.

Solution: use the newer versions Hermit 1.3.8.510 and OWL-API 5.1.0.

I posted this answer in case someone else is using the previous version and got affected.
Sincere regards.

Comment: More in general, such runtime errors point at changes in classpath between compile and runtime - often as a consequence of conflicting libraries.

Answer (score 7):

You are very near to the solution:

```
final OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
final OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("/home/galigator/myLocalDir/aura.owl"));
```

Just use **new File** instead of **IRI.create**

Comment: IRI.create((new File("/home/galigator/myLocalDir/aura.owl")).toURI())  can also be use.

Comment: Greeting Galigator, thanks for your answer. But


`final OWLOntologyManager manager =  OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
final OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("/home/../../aura.owl"));`


This is giving me the same error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SAXParsers.initParserWithOWLAPIStandards(Lorg/xml/sax/ext/DeclHandler;)Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParser;

Comment: Do you use 'maven' for your build ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, i have attached a small test java project, link: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/3787a3gsk2bwc26/test.tar.gz?dl=0

Kindly what am i doing wrong, i m sure that this code was working in the past. The project in the link is a simple test project which has an ontology for testing

Comment: I think i found out why, very strange :( i was using: 

Hermit previous maven version 1.3.8.500: net.sourceforge.owlapi org.semanticweb.hermit 1.3.8.500 and

OWL-API previous version 5.0.5: net.sourceforge.owlapi owlapi-api 5.0.5

it was working perfectly, now it does not, so i switched to the newer version of Hermit 1.3.8.510 and the newer version of OWL-API 5.1.0 and the code works again, i hope this will not affect my whole project since it was built using the previously mentioned older versions.

Comment: Thankfully nothing else has been affected. Thanks very much Galigator. I will write that in a separate answer, in case someone else is using the previous version.

Comment: When accessing a local file, always use new File rather than IRI. The reason is that an IRIDocumentSource, used for the IRI access, is slower than a file based document source.